# Robot Framework --> SeleniumLibrary

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Hi I am trying to write the code to click on this edit img, I am new at this and I am not sure how to do it. I tried using the Click button, Click Image, Click Element but since this img doesn't have any id, name or str, it's a bit challenging. Any help would be appreciated. Please look at the screenshot of the code attached.
[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9xAb.png)

[The picture of the img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bq5RX.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure this will work but you could try using xpath. In your case it would be something like this:

```
Click Element    xpath=//span[@class="mat-button-wrapper"]/mat-icon
```

There's a lot possible with xpaths. You could take a look at this cheatsheet for future reference: https://devhints.io/xpath